# What might cause layout displacement on Safari for Windows?

Tags: css, safari

I'm working on a full width layout and I haven't found problems on any browser I've tried but Safari for Windows, where the page appears slightly displaced to the right.

I thought it could be a box-sizing issue, so I tried this but it didn't solve the problem:

```
html,body {
    height:auto;    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Do you have any idea of what might be going on?

Live: http://baskra.com

Comment: Have you tried applying a [css-reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) to even out browser inconsistencies?

Comment: Towr, it doesn't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: try addding an overflow hidden

Comment: Johansrk, it didn't work as well, but thank you.

Comment: I've downloaded safari for windows (5.1.7) to have a closer look, but I don't see the displacement you mention. (Or did you fix it already?)

Comment: Towr, I'v just updated my Safari version and the problem is gone. I don't really know what happened, I did nothing to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `.nivoSlider img{max-width:none;}` this css causing issue and on windows safari in carousel there is a bit displcaement. if you remove this or comment this css it will may be work properly still need to look how does it affects other browsers

Hope it helps!